# How to replace remote Git repository with an older commit?

Tags: git

I have three Git branches on my dev server called dev, staging, and master.  These branches all exist in my remote Git repo too.  What I'm trying to do is roll back the code in the staging branch to version that was committed over a month ago and then push that code to my remote Git repo.  My current local staging branch has the same code as the remote staging branch.  I'm unsure of how to get that older commit pushed up to my remote staging branch.

Here are my local and remote branches
    git branch
    * dev
    master
    staging

```
git ls-remote
From git@bitbucket...
<hash1>   HEAD
<hash2>   refs/head/dev
<hash3>   refs/head/master
<hash4>   refs/head/staging
```

My local staging branch contains the latest code with no new work that needs to be saved.

7a58311 is the hash for the old commit I want to roll back to.  But I don't want to do a hard reset and roll back permanently to that commit.  I just want to switch to it temporarily so I can push it up to my remote staging repo and rebuild my staging server with this old branch.

```
git checkout 7a58311
...
HEAD is now at 7a58311... <commit message>
```

When I try to push it to remote I get an error.

```
git push origin HEAD:staging
! [rejected]
...
Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote...
...
```

At this point, it says to do a `git pull` but I'm not sure exactly how to do it, even after reading the documentation.  If I do a pull, I get this message:

```
git pull <remote> <branch>
```

Is the following the correct way to do the pull?  I'm afraid of entering it for fear of messing up my repos.

```
git pull refs/head/staging 7a58311
git push
```

Will doing the above put my remote staging branch at the given commit?  Keep in mind that my staging repo is always temporary.  Every time I create a new feature, I merge that feature branch into staging and push it to my staging server for testing.  If my staging server tests pass, I'll then merge the new feature branch into dev, merge dev into production, and push the feature to production.  Staging is just for testing, but in this case I want to test something against an older version of my code base.

Comment: `git push -f` ?

Comment: keep track of the hash of the current HEAD of the branch before doing a `git push -f` so that you can `git reset <hash>` when you are ready to roll all of those changes back in.

Comment: ... or better yet, tag the HEAD of the branch or push a new branch name pointing to that HEAD commit before the `git push -f` so that you are sure to be able to restore the state after you are done.